# Java template classes using generator or similar?

Tags: java, templates, generics, code-generation

Is there some library or generator that I can use to generate multiple templated java classes from a single template?

Obviously Java does have a generics implementation itself, but since it uses type-erasure, there are lots of situations where it is less than adequate.

For example, if I want to make a self-growing array like this:

```
 class EasyArray {
      T[] backingarray;
 }
```

(where T is a primitive type), then this isn't possible.

This is true for anything which needs an array, for example high-performance templated matrix and vector classes.

It should probably be possible to write a code generator which takes a templated class and generates multiple instantiations, for different types, eg for 'double' and 'float' and 'int' and 'String'.  Is there something that already exists that does this?

Edit: note that using an array of Object is not what I'm looking for, since it's no longer an array of primitives.  An array of primitives is very fast, and uses only as much space a sizeof(primitive) * length-of-array.  An array of object is an array of pointers/references, that points to Double objects, or similar, which could be scattered all over the place in memory, require garbage collection, allocation, and imply a double-indirection for access.

Edit3:

Here is code to show the difference in performance between primitive and boxed arrays:

```
int N = 10*1000*1000;
double[]primArray = new double[N];
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    primArray[i] = 123.0;
}
Object[] objArray = new Double[N];
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    objArray[i] = 123.0;
}
tic();
primArray = new double[N];
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    primArray[i] = 123.0;
}
toc();
tic();
objArray = new Double[N];
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    objArray[i] = 123.0;
}
toc();
```

Results:

```
double[] array: 148 ms
Double[] array: 4614 ms
```

Not even close!

Comment: Not Java per se, but you can use Groovy and its GStringTempateEngine

Comment: Why isn't your example possible? See [Java how to: Generic Array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Comment: @Richard, because of type erasure.  Generic types simply become "Object" at runtime.  It's not possible to create an array of a generic type in Java.  You can google "type erasure" to find out more about how they managed to implement a great feature in a crippled way.  Basically a guy, the guy who wrote Scala, came up with a cool way of implementing generics wihtout modifying the jvm.  So far so good. Then sun, in their infinite wisdom, just integrated his code directly into java, without bothering to modify the jvm and avoid the type-erasure bit, which was originally just a workaround.

Comment: @alikox, groovy is really slow.  If I wanted a slow beautiful language, I would probably just use python.  I'm using java because it runs almost as fast as C++.  Groovy does not.  Scala does.  But scala has its own problems (slow compilation, memory whore, relatively tiny community, immature libraries).

Comment: It's known that arrays and generics don't mix well.  But you can typically just use Object[] with a few casts of type:  (T) array[i].  What is the limitation that you are trying to overcome?

Comment: Did you look at the question I linked to? It demonstrates how to instantiate an generically-typed array.

Comment: @Richard and Jim, Object[] is different from for example double[].  An array of object is an array of pointers/refernces that point to Double objects stored in a separate location.  That means each double needs at least 2 * 8 = 16 bytes of storage, plus every time you access it, there is a double indirection, ie lookup the reference from the object array, then lookup the actual value from that reference. Or, you can think of the double-indirection as a process of 'unboxing'.  Either way, it's significantly slower, and uses signiicnatly more memory, than a primitive array.

Comment: All good points and good question.  I counter-upvoted you.

Comment: Having said that, you should look at the Array class which has static methods for manipulating arrays (as Richard's link suggested).  You can instantiate arrays and access specific array elements reflectively.

Comment: @Jim, regarding reflection.  Yes, using reflection everything is technically possible, but it's not going to be super-speedy.  As far as creating an array of T[] using reflection, I tried this just now.  It is possible. However, T can only be Double not double, at least, as far as i can tell?  It's basically impossible to create a template class using a primitive type in Java, I'm pretty sure?

Comment: Try this: `double[] arr = (double[])Array.newInstance(double.class, 10)`

Comment: I think the downvote was because the "solution" you're proposing is much worse than the "limitation" you're trying to get around.

Comment: The one other suggestion I can give is to try making the array itself the generic: `new Example<double[]>()`

Comment: Added code to show the difference in performance of primitive and boxed arrays: 4600msec vs 150msec.  That's a huuugggee difference!

Comment: @Richard, interesting idea.  Trying...

Comment: @Richard ,the problem is that the return type of a `get` method will be wrong, ie we can't put `T get(int index)`, since `T` is now `double[]`.  We could put `Object get(int index)`, but then it's boxed/unboxed, and we need to cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with the following draft way of doing this:

We create a class, using the placeholder type `TemplateArgOne`, and add an annotation that is used to facilitate parsing:

```
@GenerateFrom(EndlessArray.class)
public class EndlessArray {
    TemplateArgOne[] values;
    int size = 0;
    int capacity;
    public EndlessArray() {
        capacity = 10;
        values = new TemplateArgOne[capacity];
    }
    public void reserve(int newcapacity ) {
        if( newcapacity > capacity ) {
            TemplateArgOne[] newvalues = new TemplateArgOne[newcapacity];
            for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
                newvalues[i] = values[i];
            }
            values = newvalues;
            capacity = newcapacity;
        }
    }
    public void add( TemplateArgOne value ) {
        if( size >= capacity - 1 ) {
            reserve( capacity * 2);
        }
        values[size] = value;
    }
    public void set( int i, TemplateArgOne value ) {
        values[i] = value;
    }
    public TemplateArgOne get( int i ) {
        return values[i];
    }
}
```

We define TemplateArgOne as an empty class, so the above code compiles just fine, can edit it with no problems in Eclipse:

```
public class TemplateArgOne {
}
```

Now, we create a new class to instantiate the template class, and we add a couple of annotations to tell the generator which class we want to instantiate, and what type we want for `TemplateArgOne`:

```
@GenerateFrom(root.javalanguage.realtemplates.EndlessArray.class)
@GenerateArg(from=TemplateArgOne.class,to=double.class)
public class EndlessArrayDouble {

}
```

Then we run the generator, passing in the directory of our source code, and the name of the instantiation class, ie `EndlessArrayDouble`:

```
public static void main(String[] args ) throws Exception {
    new RealTemplateGenerator().go("/data/dev/machinelearning/MlPrototyping", EndlessArrayDouble.class);
}
```

And presto!  When we go to the EndlessArrayDouble class, it's been populated with our code! :

```
package root.javalanguage.realtemplates;

import root.javalanguage.realtemplates.RealTemplateGenerator.*;

@GenerateArg(from=TemplateArgOne.class,to=double.class)
@GenerateFrom(root.javalanguage.realtemplates.EndlessArray.class)
public class EndlessArrayDouble {
    double[] values;
    int size = 0;
    int capacity;
    public EndlessArrayDouble() {
        capacity = 10;
        values = new double[capacity];
    }
    public void reserve(int newcapacity ) {
        if( newcapacity > capacity ) {
            double[] newvalues = new double[newcapacity];
            for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
                newvalues[i] = values[i];
            }
            values = newvalues;
            capacity = newcapacity;
        }
    }
    public void add( double value ) {
        if( size >= capacity - 1 ) {
            reserve( capacity * 2);
        }
        values[size] = value;
    }
    public void set( int i, double value ) {
        values[i] = value;
    }
    public double get( int i ) {
        return values[i];
    }
}
```

Note that if you run it multiple times, without modifying the template class, then the instantiation class java file will not be modified, ie it wont trigger a redundant file reload in Eclipse.

The generator code:

```
//Copyright Hugh Perkins 2012, hughperkins -at- gmail
//
//This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License, 
//v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this file, You can 
//obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

package root.javalanguage.realtemplates;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RealTemplateGenerator {
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface GenerateFrom {
        Class<?> value();
    }
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface GenerateArg {
        Class<?> from();
        Class<?> to();
    }
public final static BufferedReader newBufferedReader(String filepath ) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( filepath );
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    return bufferedReader;
}

public final static BufferedWriter newBufferedWriter( String filepath ) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
    return bufferedWriter;
}

public final static ArrayList<String> readFileAsLines(String filepath ) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(40000);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = newBufferedReader(filepath);

    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    int numlines = 0;
    while( line != null ) {
        lines.add(line.substring(0, line.length() ));
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        numlines++;
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    return lines;
}

public final static void writeFileFromLines( String filepath, ArrayList<String> lines ) throws Exception {
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = newBufferedWriter(filepath);
    for( String line : lines ) {
        bufferedWriter.write(line + "\n");
    }
    bufferedWriter.close();
}

    void go( String sourcedirectory, Class<?> targetclass ) throws Exception {
        String targetclassfilepath = sourcedirectory + "/" + targetclass.getCanonicalName().replace(".","/") + ".java";
        ArrayList<String> initialLines = FileHelper.readFileAsLines(targetclassfilepath);
        String fromclassname = "";
        HashMap<String,String> argOldToNew = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ArrayList<String> generatelines = new ArrayList<String>();
        for( String line : initialLines ) {
            if( line.startsWith("@GenerateFrom")){
                fromclassname = line.split("\\(")[1].split("\\.class")[0];
            }
            if( line.startsWith("@GenerateArg")) {
                String fromclass= line.split("from=")[1].split("\\.")[0];
                String toclass = line.split("to=")[1].split("\\.")[0];
                argOldToNew.put(fromclass,toclass);
                generatelines.add(line);
            }   
        }
        Class<?> targettype = this.getClass().forName(fromclassname); 
        String fromclassfilepath = sourcedirectory + "/" + targettype.getCanonicalName().replace(".","/") + ".java";
        ArrayList<String> templateLines = FileHelper.readFileAsLines(fromclassfilepath );
        ArrayList<String> generatedLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        for( int i = 0; i < templateLines.size(); i++ ){
            String line = templateLines.get(i);
            if( !line.startsWith("@GenerateFrom") && !line.startsWith("@GenerateArg")) {
                for( String oldarg : argOldToNew.keySet() ) {
                    line = line.replace(oldarg, argOldToNew.get(oldarg));
                }
                line = line.replace(targettype.getSimpleName(), targetclass.getSimpleName());
            } else if( line.startsWith("@GenerateFrom") ) {
                for( String generateline : generatelines ) {
                    generatedLines.add(generateline);
                }
            }
            generatedLines.add(line);
        }
        boolean isModified = false;
        if( initialLines.size() != generatedLines.size() ) {
            isModified = true;
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < initialLines.size(); i++ ) {
                if( !initialLines.get(i).equals(generatedLines.get(i))) {
                    isModified = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if( isModified ) {
            FileHelper.writeFileFromLines(targetclassfilepath, generatedLines);
            System.out.println("Generated " + targetclassfilepath );
        } else {
            System.out.println("No change to " + targetclassfilepath );         
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args ) throws Exception {
        new RealTemplateGenerator().go("/data/dev/machinelearning/MlPrototyping", EndlessArrayDouble.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice job. A couple of ideas: I would make `TemplateArgOne` a real type parameter rather than a class. This way you could use the code generator on existing generic classes like `ArrayList`. This would also be more self documenting. And rather than parsing Java files yourself, you can have `javac` parse it for you and give you a complete annotated source tree. So your generator would not break if you had a string containing `TemplateArgOne` in your source. See project Lombok for a working code generator of this sort. Also see `javax.annotation.processing` API documentations.

Comment: @Saintali, when you say 'real type parameter', I assume you mean a 'standard java generics type parameter'?  Unfortunately, as far as i know, java generics type parmeters cannot be primitive classes.

Comment: @Santali, Project Lombok looks pretty cool. It looks like it could be part of the future of an easier-to-use java.  It doesn't as far as I can tell handle primitive template types?  If you put a link to project lombok in an answer, I will upvote it.